# "Cannot associate card with accounts on this marketplace" error when adding a card to an account.

Tags: balanced-payments

I tokenized a card with Balanced.js, and am attempting to create a buyer with the buyer email and the tokenized card URI.  I'm seeing this error:

```
Balanced::Conflict(409)::Conflict:: POST 
https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/marketplaces/TEST-xxxxxx/accounts: cannot-associate-card: Cannot associate card with accounts on this marketplace. Your request id is xxxxxx
```

Any ideas on the source of the error and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually an indicator that you're trying to associate a Card that was tokenized on one marketplace with an Account that exists on another marketplace. Cards tokenized in Balanced can only be associated accounts on the same marketplace.

The often happens if you're moving between test and production environments. The most obvious place to look is at the `marketplace_uri` parameter that you're passing through to [balanced.js](https://www.balancedpayments.com/docs/js).

You'll see some code in your javascript that looks like

```
balanced.init(marketplaceUri);
```

That uri must be the same as the marketplace that is associated with the API key that you're using to process payments.

Comment: This same fix also works when you get the error message "unable to associate bank account with accounts on this marketplace"

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the api key
    require 'balanced'
    Balanced.configure('')

To find it go to dashboard > settings > api key secret